# Netbeans Missing source tab

Tags: netbeans, tabs, editor

I have loaded up netbeans, and all it is showing me is the history tab when i go to edit my code for my projects. I went on to view >> editors, but the only editor that was there was the History. How do i get the Source tab back?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, similar issue, after fresh installation, was resolved by closing the running Netbeans IDE instance, then renaming the existing Netbeans folder found inside the C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\ on Windows 7.

Might be helpful, refer the following links -
[here](https://forums.netbeans.org/topic59936.html) & [FaqWhatIsUserdir](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir)